# Exception error does not happen and try ... catch is not printing specified error message

Tags: java, exception

I have the following code which attempts to run and print a specified error message when the file is not found. However, it's running perfectly without giving output about the error that happens. the text file name does not exist in my directory. Can anyone shed some light on this?

When I run this it runs perfectly without any error (not sure if that's a good thing).

```
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
   import java.io.BufferedWriter;
   import java.io.FileWriter;
   import java.io.BufferedReader;
   import java.io.IOException;

   public class filereader {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
      String fileName = "nonExistenceFileName.csv";

      File textFile = new File(fileName);

      try (BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(textFile))) {
        String line;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(textFile);
          while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            line = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
          }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Can't find file " + textFile.toString());
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to read file");
      }
```

Comment: Can you please attach error logs as well.

Comment: Hi @DineshKondapaneni as mentioned in the question there's no error prompted when i compile and run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to create a **BufferWriter** object on a non-existing file
`BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(textFile));` 
it creates a new file (if not already exists) 
 
[image]

So no exception is thrown since the file is already present

Comment: thanks Chris! that's exactly what i was looking for.  I was checking the existence of file before compiling that's why i didn't notice the new file was created if it doesn't exist in by BufferedWriter (which i used wrongly. should have use BufferedReader instead)

Answer (score 1):

you should check if the file exist before, otherwise, **BufferWriter** creates one if it doesn't exist. use

```
    if (textFile.exists()){
    //what to do if file exist
    }else{
      //Throw FileNotFound Error
    }
```